# Checking if pip is install via script

Tags: python, shell, pip

So this may have been a dumb way of doing it but I wanted to check if pip was installed via a script, so I ran the pip version command and checked if the first 3 characters of the command were "pip" and if so I could say I knew pip was installed. Problem is when I run this and get a `command not found` error, the logic still thinks pip is installed. Why is? What is that `command not found` error returning? It can't be pip right so why does pip not install? And what's a better way of detecting if pip is installed?

```
pip=$(sudo /root/.local/bin/pip -V | cut -c 1-3)
if [[ pip != "pip" ]]; then
    echo "Installing pip..."
    curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o /tmp/get-pip.py
    sudo /workplace/user/package/src/EnvImprovement/bin/python2.7 get-pip.py --user
else
    echo "Pip detected."
fi
```

Comment: In this line [[pip != "pip"]], may I know why there is a list inside another list? Is it causing an issue?

Comment: @RajeshKumar This is syntax that I was seeing when I was looking up shell script conditionals. I can edit it and see if this causes a problem though. I don't believe it is though.

Comment: @RajeshKumar: This is a shell script, not Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing whether the string `pip` is equal to the string `pip`, which it is. The `pip` variable isn't involved.

Unlike in Python, `pip` and `"pip"` are equivalent in a shell script. The quotes in `"pip"` [suppress special interpretation of a number of characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes), none of which are actually present in `pip` anyway. You need `$pip` to perform variable expansion.

Even then, hardcoding `/root/.local/bin/pip` doesn't make much sense, and executing pip by a hardcoded path to determine whether it exists seems like a strange idea compared to testing whether an executable exists at that path, or taking a different approach altogether.

You should probably use [`command -v pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) instead of your current approach.

Comment: Wow I left off the $ I can't believe it. Thanks.